# My JRadioButtons arent interacting with my JButton

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jradiobutton

```
public Quiz(){
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setTitle("x");
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    label = new JLabel("What is...?");
    frame.add(label);

    choiceA = new JRadioButton("A", true); 

            //this if statement happens even if I click on one of the other radio buttons and if I leave this one set to false then none of the events happen

    choiceB = new JRadioButton("B");
    choiceC = new JRadioButton("C");
    choiceD = new JRadioButton("D");
    frame.add(choiceA);
    frame.add(choiceB);
    frame.add(choiceC);
    frame.add(choiceD);

    group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(choiceA);
    group.add(choiceB);
    group.add(choiceC);
    group.add(choiceD);


    checkButton = new JButton("Check");
    frame.add(checkButton);

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    checkButton.addActionListener(handler);
    choiceA.addActionListener(handler);
    choiceB.addActionListener(handler);
    choiceC.addActionListener(handler);
    choiceD.addActionListener(handler);


}


public static void main (String args[]){
    Quiz quiz = new Quiz();
    quiz.frame.setResizable(false);
    quiz.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    quiz.frame.setVisible(true);
}

private class Handler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        checkButtonActionPerformed(event);

        }

    public void checkButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        Quiz quiz = new Quiz();
        if(quiz.choiceA.isSelected()){
            System.out.println("wow");
        }
        else if(quiz.choiceB.isSelected()){
            System.out.println("not wow");
        }
        else if(quiz.choiceD.isSelected()){
            System.out.println("why doesn't this work?");
        }
    }
}
}
```

I just want each string to print out after its chosen and the `JButton` is pressed but none of them work unless I set one of them to true before I run the code and if I do that it doesn't matter which radio button I have checked, when I hit the `JButton` to does the if statement for the one I originally had set to true

Comment: this is my first time using this site. sorry if the format is awful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you are creating a new instance of `Quiz` in your `actionPerformed` method...

```
public void checkButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    Quiz quiz = new Quiz();
```

This means that what you are comparing isn't what's actually on the screen.

If the `Handler` is an inner class, you can reference the variables directly...

```
if(choiceA.isSelected()){...}
```

Otherwise you should be passing a reference of the `Quiz` to the `Handler` for it to use, but I would suggest this gets more complicated as you would, realistically need some kind of getter methods that could tell what has being selected

Comment: Wow you are the man! I would have never figured that out. I'm new to programing so I'm still figuring out why things work the way they do. I can't express my gratitude enough. I was getting pretty mad at this dilemma. Thanks man